# TypeError: only() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python-3.x, flask, cassandra, cql

Here I am trying to get only two fields from cassandra using only() but when I am passing field names it's giving me above error, I have also tried passing **self** but did't work. After getting those two fields I need to convert them in two arrays so that I can plot the graph with names and marks.

Here is the code:

```
from flask import *
from flask_cqlalchemy import CQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CASSANDRA_HOSTS'] = ['127.0.0.1']
app.config['CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE'] = "emp"

db = CQLAlchemy(app)

class Student(db.Model):
    uid = db.columns.Integer(primary_key=True)
    marks = db.columns.Integer(primary_key=True)
    username = db.columns.Text(required=True)
    password = db.columns.Text()

    @app.route('/meriting')
    def show_meritlist():
        ob = Student.objects().filter().only(Student.marks, Student.username)
        ob = ob.filter(Student.marks >= 65).allow_filtering()
        return render_template('merit.html', ml = ob)

db.sync_db()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 2):

`only()` takes only one parameter that should be an iterable. Try:

```
ob = Student.objects().filter().only((Student.marks, Student.username))
```

Comment: It's leading to this: TypeError: unhashable type: 'ColumnQueryEvaluator'

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that. Maybe related to this https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-494 (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011190/typeerror-unhashable-type-usertype-when-creating-a-cassandra-python-driver-mode)? Do you get the traceback on the same line?

Comment: Well, it's ok. I am referring this link  <https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.21/api/cassandra/cqlengine/query/>

Comment: You might want to ask a different question or edit this one, as my answer specifically addressed the error you were getting. That way you might attract someone with knowledge about what you are trying to achieve. Good luck!